# Click event for dynamically added li element?

Tags: jquery

I am having totally 20 links.First 10 links directly visible to user and remaining 10 links shown when user hover the down arrow image(used for hover). When user click any one hover link, the link till the currently clicked are moved to left side(another down arrow used for add the right side links to left side dynamically by creating li). This one working fine.But this is not working as vice versa. (i.e)When i click left side link it should navigate to right side.Click event not working for li element that i created dynamically. Please Can any one help for me??????

My sample Code:

```
//To append the line from right hover to looplink div
$('#loop_link').append('<li id="pagelinkli_'+val3+'">'+$('#pagelinkli_'+val3).html()+'</li>');

//To hide the link in right hover div once it selected and appended in loop link div
$('#pagelink_a  #pagelinkli_'+val3).css('display','none');

//This line to move the link from loop link to left hover div
$('#pagelink_a_left ul').prepend(('<li id="pagelinkli_'+val6+'">'+$('#pagelinkli_'+val6).html()+'</li>'));

//This line to hide the link in looplink div              
$('#loop_link #pagelinkli_'+val6).css('display','none');
```

**This code is like navigating link from right hover to tab and from tab to left hover and vice versa.....**

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/jquery-event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: //To append the line frm right hover to looplink div $('#loop_link').append('<li id="pagelinkli_'+val3+'">'+$('#pagelinkli_'+val3).html()+'</li>');
//To hide the link in right hover div once it selected and appended in loop link  div                                               $('#pagelink_a  #pagelinkli_'+val3).css('display','none');
//To  move the link from loop link to left hover div   $('#pagelink_a_left ul').prepend(('<li id="pagelinkli_'+val6+'">'+$('#pagelinkli_'+val6).html()+'</li>'));
//To hide the link in looplink div       $('#loop_link #pagelinkli_'+val6).css('display','none')

Answer (score 3):

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$("#pagelink_a_left").on("click", "li", function() {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yakbQ/

Comment: Hi Thank u for your answer. But, I am getting "TypeError: $(".listContainer").on is not a function" Error.......... My sample code "$('#loop_link').append('<li id="pagelinkli_'+val3+'">'+$('#pagelinkli_'+val3).html()+'</li>');"

Comment: Change .listContainer to #loop_link

Comment: //To append the line frm right hover to looplink div $('#loop_link').append('<li id="pagelinkli_'+val3+'">'+$('#pagelinkli_'+val3).html()+'</li>');
//To hide the link in right hover div once it selected and appended in loop link  div                                               $('#pagelink_a  #pagelinkli_'+val3).css('display','none');
//To  move the link from loop link to left hover div   $('#pagelink_a_left ul').prepend(('<li id="pagelinkli_'+val6+'">'+$('#pagelinkli_'+val6).html()+'</li>'));
//To hide the link in looplink div       $('#loop_link #pagelinkli_'+val6).css('display','none')

Comment: Please help me to write click function for left hover li element($('#pagelink_a_left li')).Not for looplink div

Comment: Change `$("#loop_link")` to `$("#pagelink_a_left")`

Comment: getting "$("#pagelink_a_left").on is not a function" error. I am using "jquery1.7.2-min.js"..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yakbQ/ - Works just fine, So either you didn't load jQuery, or got the wrong version, Or made a typo. Either way, above code works. I strongly advise you to read up on basic jQuery, as it looks like you could use some more knowledge about it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the new link are added dynamically and wasn't the part of DOM when the page was loaded.

SO you can use `live` jquery function (LIVE is deprecated so i will not suggest)
or you can use something like this

```
$("body").on("click", "link div", function() {
    $('#loop_link').append('<li id="pagelinkli_'+val3+'">'+$('#pagelinkli_'+val3).html()+'</li>')
});
```

Comment: Hi Thank u for your answer. But, I am getting "TypeError: $(".listContainer").on is not a function" Error.......... My sample code "$('#loop_link').append('<li id="pagelinkli_'+val3+'">'+$('#pagelinkli_'+val3).html()+'</li>');"

Comment: //To append the line frm right hover to looplink div $('#loop_link').append('<li id="pagelinkli_'+val3+'">'+$('#pagelinkli_'+val3).html()+'</li>');
//To hide the link in right hover div once it selected and appended in loop link  div                                               $('#pagelink_a  #pagelinkli_'+val3).css('display','none');
//To  move the link from loop link to left hover div   $('#pagelink_a_left ul').prepend(('<li id="pagelinkli_'+val6+'">'+$('#pagelinkli_'+val6).html()+'</li>'));
//To hide the link in looplink div       $('#loop_link #pagelinkli_'+val6).css('display','none')

Answer (score -1):

Try to use on instead of bind or directly using click function.

Try to use the below script.

```
$(".listContainer").on("click","li",function() {

});
```

on method will let you bind the click event for the elements that are dynamically (+ the elements that are already present) getting generated.

As per many ppls suggestion changed live method as on

Comment: `live();` is deprecated. Use `on();` instead

Comment: `live()` is deprecated .Use `on()`.

Comment: Hi Thank u for your answer. But, I am getting "TypeError: $(".listContainer").on is not a function" Error.......... My sample code "$('#loop_link').append('<li id="pagelinkli_'+val3+'">'+$('#pagelinkli_'+val3).html()+'</li>');"

Comment: //To append the line frm right hover to looplink div $('#loop_link').append('<li id="pagelinkli_'+val3+'">'+$('#pagelinkli_'+val3).html()+'</li>');
//To hide the link in right hover div once it selected and appended in loop link  div                                               $('#pagelink_a  #pagelinkli_'+val3).css('display','none');
//To  move the link from loop link to left hover div   $('#pagelink_a_left ul').prepend(('<li id="pagelinkli_'+val6+'">'+$('#pagelinkli_'+val6).html()+'</li>'));
//To hide the link in looplink div       $('#loop_link #pagelinkli_'+val6).css('display','none')

Comment: Make sure that you are using jQuery version 1.7
on method is added only in 1.7